# Helpers for walk through and searching node in the tree structure (D3.js way)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, helper

When I working with tree-structured data in the d3.js I often need to call `forEach` or `filter` analog on the data.
For example, here is the data:

```
data = {
  id: 0,
  children: [ {
    id: 1,
    children: [ ... ]
  }, {
    id: 2,
    children: [ ... ]
  }]
}
```

To check if the node with id = 5 exists in the data I have to implement the recursive search function through all the children. Something like this:

```
function hasNodeWithId(node, id) {
    if (node.id === id) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return _.any(node.children || [],
            function(n) { return hasNodeWithId(n, id); });
    }
}
```

The search of the node inside the tree is such a common task so I wonder if there are some sort of helper functions in the d3.js library for this. If not, then how do others approach this sort of problems?

P.S.
Sometimes I can use the `tree.nodes` function to get a flat array:

```
var theId = 5,
    tree = d3.layout.tree(),
    nodes = tree.nodes(data), // makes a flat array of all the nodes in the data
    theNode = nodes.filter(function(d) { return d.id === theId; });
```

But calling `tree.nodes(data)` every time I need to walk through the data is overwhelming and has some side effects (`x`, `y`, `depth` fields) on `data`.